# GWT can't find org.json while it's in the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I have a strange problem. I get an error from Google Web Toolkit stating the following:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract 
com.pluspopularity.model.LinkItem com.pluspopularity.web.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) 
throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

Now, I can find lots of questions about this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException` exception, but they all seem to be fixed by GWT version 2.5 because `org.json` was since then included in the `gwt-dev.jar` package.

I have version 2.5 and I can see `org.json` in my GWT SDK library.

So I have no idea where this error comes from.

Something I noticed: the GWT SDK folder contains a lot of jar files, but only 4 are included when I add it as an SDK in Eclipse: `gwt-user.jar`, `gwt-dev.jar`, `validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar` and `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`. In some issues in questions about this error from GWT versions before 2.5 I see mentions of a `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` file. That file sits inside my GWT SDK folder, but it's not included in the SDK library in Eclipse.
I re-installed the GWT SDK via Eclipse but still only those 4 files are included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error at runtime (apparently), on the server-side.

If the Eclipse plugin doesn't do it for you (I have no idea if it's supposed to do it or not), you should go get `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` (or any JAR that contains `org.json`) and copy it to your `WEB-INF/lib` next to `gwt-servlet.jar`.

Comment: Eclipse should display a warning (in Problems tab) that this library won't be available on the server. A click on QuickFix should offer an option to copy it to WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I do not have the Warning but I'll try it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

org.json.JSONException is present in **json-20090211.jar**.

[image]

Both gwt-user and request-factory-server have dependency on it. In a maven set up it gets copied automatically via request-factory for us since both are in runtime scope.

Comment: Obviously the OP is not using Maven, it sure wouldn't be a problem otherwise.

Comment: If the org.json.JSONException is present in json-20090211. Should this not be the jar included in WEB-INF/lib instead of bigger jar with other stuff in gwt-servlet-deps.jar .

Comment: Sure it could, but it then has to be downloaded separately, whereas gwt-servlet-deps.jar is just there. That being said, I can't understand that people nowadays don't use managed dependencies (Maven, Ivy, etc.) and, worse, use Eclipse as their "build tools".

Comment: Like I said, I have `org.json` in my built path. For some reason it had to be in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
Besides, I just use the default `Run` functionality of Eclipse, why wouldn't I. And about Maven, I only recently read about it for the first time, was about to wait till my exams are over and read more about it.